# Windows how to create directory symlink

Tags: windows, magento, symlink

im trying to create a symlink to directory Windows 8.1

using git-bash command windows run as administrator

having the folder structure like this:

```
-magento plugin
-magento
```

where my plugin is a git repository i want to symlink it to magento as mentioned here: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-setup-git-for-magento-extension-development/

so i run command to create symlink

```
$ ln -s D:/wamp/www/plugin-magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/company/name/ d:/wamp/www/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/
company/name
```

where:
`D:/wamp/www/plugin-magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/company/name/` has subdirectories and exist

and 
`d:/wamp/www/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/` exist

i get error:
ln: creating symbolic link `d:/wamp/www/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/def
ault/template/company/name' to`D:/wamp/www/plugin-magento/app/design/adminhtml/def
ault/default/template/company/name/': No such file or directory

Answer (score 11):

Under Windows you create a symlink with **mklink /d**. Attention under Windows its target and then source.

```
mklink /d "D:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\
company\name\" "D:\wamp\www\plugin-magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\company\name\"
```

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/278262-mklink-create-use-links-windows.html

Comment: it returns `Invalid switch - "wamp".`

Comment: and when i wrap paths in `""` quates then it returns `The system can not find the path specified.`

Comment: Put it in " or use \ the option **/d** is for a directory. If you wand to link a file then remove the **/d**

Comment: when i use `/d` its still returns `No such file or directory`

Comment: Then check your path ;)

Comment: when i type the path in exploreer it works and when i want to create symlink it doesnt