# "The system cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe"

Tags: java, environment-variables

I am on JDK 8u25 on Windows 8, and I am experiencing a problem with my Java installation. I can run `javac` perfectly fine, but running `java` produces this error message:

```
The system cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
```

How do I fix this?

---

I think the problem has to do with my environment variables.

The important variables, as I have set them, are:

- `JAVA_HOME` – `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25`
- `CLASSPATH` – `.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib`
- `PATH` – `<other paths omitted>;%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

And their expansions, as viewed with `set` in cmd, are:

- `JAVA_HOME` – `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25`
- `CLASSPATH` – `.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\lib;%CLASSPATH%;`
- `PATH` – `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;<other paths omitted>;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin`

The full output of `set` can be viewed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjrrg.png).

Comment: check this link to know how to set environment variables. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1672281/4083590

Comment: @johny What I did is similar to the post on the link. Do I not need a \lib at the end of classpath? I tried it with and without. I still got the error message when I tried to run the class file.

Comment: you can check your environment variables by opening up a Command Prompt and type `set`

Comment: it would be good if you provide a screen shot of the environment variables as @CocoNess told.

Comment: an irrelevant question though.. is it dangerous to reveal my environment variables like that??

Comment: Your screenshot has a strange character instead of a \ . Why? I cant identify the character. It's probably not a good idea to reveal your environment variables. You should only show the relevant ones

Comment: here is a picture of the related environment variables: http://i58.tinypic.com/5aq4om.jpg

Comment: @CocoNess It is the equivalent of the '\' sign. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 56):

I've got a similar problem I'm currently working on solving. I can't say this will solve your error since there may be issues with other software (which is my case with Eclipse Luna).

Java is using the path given in your PATH variable, which is,

```
  C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

Go to this folder (ProgramData is hidden, so unhide it if necessary) and right click on the java.exe symlink. You'll see in the Target field where it's looking for java.exe. It may be pointing to the java.exe file from your previous jdk1.6.0_45 install. Either paste in new shortcuts here or change the PATH setting as others have mentioned.

I've found that the Java installer doesn't change the javapath or update the system path, at least when going from 1.8 to 1.7. In my case changing the shortcuts only led to a problem with Eclipse on startup.

EDIT:-----
After playing with javapath folder shortcuts it turns out you need symlinks, at least for Eclipse. See, [Windows how to create directory symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240286/windows-how-to-create-directory-symlink#24240393).

You don't need the /d switch for a file symlink,

```
  cd C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath 

  mklink java.exe "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\java.exe"
  mklink javaw.exe "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\javaw.exe"
  mklink javaws.exe "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\javaws.exe"
```

This now works for me.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on Windows 7 - due to a recent change in how it handles symlinks, its GUI displays an error saying it cannot find "java[w/ws].exe" when using symlinks. It's safer to just create a directory junction: `rmdir /s /q %ProgramData%\Oracle\Java\javapath & mlink /d %ProgramData%\Oracle\Java\javapath %ProgramFiles%\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin`

Comment: Before running those mklink, make sure to `cd C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` and `del java*.exe`, otherwise you'll create the new symbolic links in your current cmd directory...

Comment: You may need to be running your command prompt as administrator, otherwise you might run into permissions problems (as Igor may have above).

Comment: I am wondered why java even requires for something to be in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath" directory. This is quite confusing. What should I do if I want to target different JDK?

Answer (score 21):

Why Oracle did such a poor way to point to java is beyond me. We solved this problem by creating a new link to the JDK

```
mklink /d C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\"
```

The same would work for a JRE if that is all that is required.

This replaces the old symlinks in `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` (if they existed previously)

Comment: this works for java but not for javac: cannot find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main

Comment: `Why Oracle did such a poor way to point to java is beyond me` I guess the reason was that when you have relatively constant env var (pointing always to the one place - f.e. `javapath` folder), you can change paths dynamically, on on the fly (changing a link does not require shell restart). While if you change env var (f.e. PATH) you'll have to restart shell to reload and apply new ENVVARs values. Sure I'm not an Oracle advocate and of course it's just my suggestion.

Comment: I received "Cannot create a file when that file already exists."

Answer (score 15):

I had in `PATH`:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;<others omitted>
```

I removed:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
```

and that fixed the issue for me. `java -version` now gives details about the Java version, etc.

Comment: This has just fixed the issue for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This will solve all problems relating to Java and environment variables:

1. Make your way to Windows' [Environment Variables dialog](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).
2. Under **System variables**, select the variable named **Path**. Click **Edit...**
3. Remove the entry that looks like:

   ```
   C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
   ```
4. Add the path of your JDK/JRE's `bin` folder.
5. Don't forget to set **JAVA_HOME**.

Answer (score 5):

I got same error while running JAVA command. To resolve this, I moved the java path as the first entry in the path, and it resolved the issue. Please have look at this screenshot for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Updating the PATH Environment Variable**

If you do not set the PATH variable, you need to specify the full path to the executable file every time you run it, such as:

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\javac" MyClass.java
```

It is useful to set the PATH variable permanently so it will persist after rebooting.

To set the PATH variable permanently, add the full path of the jdk1.8.0\bin directory to the PATH variable. Typically, this full path looks something like

 `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin`.
 **Set the PATH variable as follows on Microsoft Windows:**

- Click Start, then Control Panel, then System.
- Click Advanced, then Environment Variables.
- Add the location of the bin folder of the JDK installation to the PATH variable in System Variables. 

  The following is a typical value for the PATH variable:

  C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin


  **Note:**
- The PATH environment variable is a series of directories separated by semicolons (;) and is not case-sensitive. Microsoft Windows looks for programs in the PATH directories in order, from left to right.
- You should only have one bin directory for a JDK in the path at a time. Those following the first instance are ignored.
- If you are not sure where to add the JDK path, append it.

The new path takes effect in each new command window you open after setting the PATH variable.

Comment: Source : [Java Installation Instructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/install-windows-189425.html)

Answer (score 2):

1. Uninstall all JDKs installed on your computer from the Java Control Panel
2. Search for `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java` and delete that directory and all files contained within. You can do this from the command line using `rmdir /S C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java`
3. Then search for C:\ProgramData\Oracle and delete the oracle folder. You can do this using `rmdir /S C:\ProgramData\Oracle`
4. Now install JDK and set the path.
5. Run the program.You won't find the same problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 versions of jdk in your `PATH VARIABLE` `jdk1.6.0_45` and `jdk1.8.0_25`. Try removing the first one ie.  `jdk1.6.0_45` from the `PATH`

Comment: I checked and I noticed there was something from the java 6 version but I couldn't get rid of it. Do you know what this error means? pic: http://i62.tinypic.com/vxn0vn.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a corporate PC that's fairly restricted by group policy, this might work....

Assuming that

1. your Windows `PATH` includes `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`
2. you have JDK installed to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin`

Then create the following text file `mklink.bat` and put it on your desktop:

```
rem mklink.bat
mklink /d C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin"
pause
```

Now right-click it and choose "Run as Administrator". Provide admin credentials. The script should report success. Now you can compile or run Java.

Answer (score 1):

This problem exists when you upgrade from one version to another.because jdk is not automatically upgraded.

For the same you can change the environmental varibles.
In system variables look for the **PATH** and add the jdk bin location in the front of the string(not at the back).
Once you have done that check in CMD if "**java**" and "**javac**" works.
if it works, again go to system variables.
add "**CLASSPATH**" A the variable and set value " **.
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\lib;**"

Comment: please do tell what is your question. what are your progress . explain more and with proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you update the java,
the easiest way to solve this is to just uninstall the JDK & then reinstall it.
NOTE: This doesnt remove the path or classpath so no need to worry.

Answer (score 0):

There must be two or more PATH variables. Try merging all of them into one using semi-colon (;)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same after installing java8 from a non-permissioned account.
To fix I simply reinstalled from admin user account.
This created the quoted directory with file links to java exes.

Answer (score 0):

I had also similar problem where by I had to un-install JDK 1.8 and needed jdk 1.7. 
What i did was removed the symbolic links from the javapath and then imported the shortcuts of java, javaw, javaws from the bin directory to the javapath folder. However, I found some permission issues in the enterprise laptop where by I did not have the privilege to modify/ update this directory. I had given appropriate permission from the administrator and there by resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

`c:\ProgramData\Java\javapath` is used for symlinks. You can of course add the full path to your Java Path to `%PATH%`, but equally you can create a symlink to the path to the above location.

1. Open `CMD` as Administrator.
2. Type `mklink java.exe` (full path to your Java.exe)
   eg

`mklink java.exe "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry.
Just uninstall jdk as well as jdk updates
Before re installing jdk ,delete the oracle folder inside programData hidden folder in C:\ 
Then reinstall.
Set the following,

```
JAVA_HOME
CLASSPATH
PATH
JRE_HOME ( is optional)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe" from the Path variable and add your jdk bin path. It will work.

In my case the I have removed the the above path and added my JDK path which is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin"

Answer (score 0):

For New version of Java JavaPath folder is located

64 bit OS

`"C:\Program Files \Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\"`

X86

`"C:\Program Files(x86) \Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\"`

Answer (score 0):

This will solve all problems relating to Java and environment variables:

Make your way to Windows' Environment Variables dialog.
Under System variables, select the variable named Path. Click Edit...
Remove the entry that looks like:

C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
Add the path of your JDK/JRE's bin folder.

Don't forget to set JAVA_HOME.

This helped me.......:-)

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked like this:
On your desktop go to `Search->View advanced system settings->Environment Variables`
Under System Variables look for path and click `Edit`.
Click on `New` and add the new Path and move it to the top.
To find your java path if you don't know where it is installed in cmd type `where javac`

Answer (score -1):

<>\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\ is now created as a junction, no symlinks anymore

Comment: Add more descriptive answer.

Answer (score -1):

Faced the same issue while upgrading to OpenJDK17 from JDK8 and got this error while executing **Java -version** in cmd.

Fix: goto path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin copy files **java.exe** and **javaw.exe**, goto path C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath and delete the existing shortcuts( I had java 8 before this and shortcuts were placed to java.exe, javaw.exe & javaws.exe.) and paste these two files there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).