# Running Java Programs in Windows 10 Command Prompt

Tags: java, windows

I recently downloaded Java SDK 8.0 on my computer running Windows 10. However, when I looked on the Internet for how to use Java in the Windows 10 Command Prompt, I was only able to get the `javac` command to work in the prompt. When I tried to run my program, the command prompt said that it could not find the `java.exe` file. Does anyone know how to make Java work in Windows 10? (I'm using the x86 version of Java.)

Comment: Add the directory where `java.exe` is to the environment variable `path`

Comment: It's the same directory as the `javac.exe` file, and that one works.

Comment: You may have different version installed. Java on Windows can be installed into the Windows directory itself, which can mess things up, but I think that's the JRE.  The JDK also installs the JRE

Comment: So the only files that are unrecognized are the programs with the Java icon next to them. Does this help at all? Also this is the directory path for `java.exe`: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin`

Comment: Have you tried running the command console as admin or in compatibility mode.  Can't say I've had any issues...

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Comment: Have you tried to run it directly (qualified)? `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe" -version`

Comment: It says this: `java version "1.8.0_60" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode, sharing)`

Comment: So Java is running fine, which means that if a plain `java -versions` doesn't work, your `PATH` is misconfigured.

Comment: What is the exact error message (including path info)?  Recent versions of Java add `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` to the path and then the exes in `javapath` are actually symlinks to the real exes.  Maybe the links are messed up.

Comment: The error says: "The system cannot find the file C;\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe"

Comment: Sounds like symbolic link problem.  [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27572837/523391) might help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve the error: The system cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864662/how-to-solve-the-error-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-c-programdata-oracle-ja)

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't actually have to be *installed*. You can run any Java that's available to you.

This is sometimes useful for running Java from a network share.

Try running the `java.exe` program by fully qualifying it. If it runs that way, your problem is with your `PATH`.

---

To illustrate that you can run any Java by qualifing it, I have 9 JDK's and 1 JRE installed:

- 32-bit JDK: Versions 1.4, 5, 6, 7, and 8
- 64-bit JDK: Versions 5, 6, 7, and 8
- 32-bit JRE: Version 8

Copied from a single command prompt window:

```
C:\>"C:\prog\java32\jdk1.4.2_19\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.4.2_19"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.4.2_19-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.4.2_19-b04, mixed mode)

C:\>"C:\prog\java32\jdk1.5.0_22\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.5.0_22"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_22-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_22-b03, mixed mode)

C:\>"C:\prog\java32\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\>"C:\prog\java32\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\>"C:\prog\java32\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)

C:\>"C:\prog\java64\jdk1.5.0_22\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.5.0_22"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_22-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.5.0_22-b03, mixed mode)

C:\>"C:\prog\java64\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

C:\>"C:\prog\java64\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

C:\>"C:\prog\java64\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)

C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt `cmd` and type `where java` , this will output where java executable is, then you can go to `System Propreties>Advanced>Environement Variables>` *(Right click on computer and click on Propreties)* 
and add the `where java` output to the `PATH` variable separated with a *semi-colon* `;`