# Not able to set JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, java-8, java-7, java-6

I have 3 installed versions of `java (1.6,1.7,1.8)` in my machine. Java alternatives has been configured to Java 1.8. So whenever i type `java -version` it is picking up from alternatives and showing `java 1.8`.

Here now i want to use other version of `java (1.6 or 1.7)`, for that i have tried updating the .bashrc with other java paths. But still it is showing alternatives version (1.8)

[image]

Is there any way to override alternatives java from user level.

Comment: What have you done _exactly_? Alternatives links `/usr/lib/jvm/java.../bin/java` to (via a number of indirections) to `/usr/bin/java` - what have you done to change this?

Comment: use alternatives to change the java version, all the java versions will be numbered, chose the version you want, thats it.

Comment: Try the steps on this link it should do your job. http://ask.xmodulo.com/change-default-java-version-linux.html

Comment: As your title speaks about `JAVA_HOME`: This variable is not used by the operating system for finding executables. It is the `PATH` variable, that you have to change if you want to use another Java version.

Comment: i have added screenshot of the scenario

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blogpost explaining how to change jdk version in a *nix environment from terminal:

https://www.jayway.com/2014/01/15/how-to-switch-jdk-version-on-mac-os-x-maverick/

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change your environment to switch Java version.

You can simply qualify the version you want to use. Alternatively, just make sure the version you want is *first* on the PATH, not last.

See my old answer for examples. It's for Windows, but it should work similarly for Linux.
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/32365879/5221149

Comment: It's very difficult to use your method. whenever i run java program by default it will pick from alternatives or .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix

I did like below

`export PATH:new_java_path:$PATH`. Now it started working for the current session.