# How can I change JVM implementation (e.g. HotSpot, GraalVM, OpenJ9 e.t.c.) when running JVM-compatible programs (Java, Kotlin, Scala e.t.c.)?

Tags: java, linux, graalvm, jvm-hotspot

I need to change JVM implementation to compare which one is more suitable for requirements I need to meet. How can I achieve this? Specifically on GNU/Linux or MacOS. Is there a way to set JVM implementation when running java program with `java` console command? Or maybe I need to change some lib file that contains JVM implementation?
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: "java" console command is converted to full path by O/S. You can use your own full path, like "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have multiple JVMs on your machine, you can simply qualify which one you want, when you execute the `java` command.

At least the Oracle JVM on Windows works like that. I haven't tried on Linux, or with any of the others, but the JVM doesn't need to be on the PATH, you can just qualify which one you want.

See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32365879/5221149) for examples of how that works.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to have multiple JVM implementations on a machine, you simply put each one in its own directory.  Personally, I use `/opt` on Linux but you can choose where to put them.

Then, all you need to do is change your `PATH` environment variable to ensure that the first directory in the list that has a java executable is the one you want to use, e.g.

```
PATH=/opt/JDK8/bin:$PATH
```

You can also set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable but that does not directly impact which JVM is used, it is just a convention used by other applications (like Tomcat).  By doing this you can set your PATH once,

```
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and then just change the JAVA_HOME variable to reflect which version of Java you want to use.

This works on both Linux and Mac (which is a UNIX based OS).