# Is it possible to select the JAVA version without changing the computer settings?

Tags: java

Both java 8 and java 11 are installed on a server, default settings (JAVA_HOME) show java 11.
Is it possible to run the code with java 8 without creating the jar file or by selecting java 8 while running the jar file?

Comment: Can you give more context? You could just use an absolute path to your Java8 installation (`/use/lib/java-11/bin/java` for instance) rather than using just `java` to run it.

Comment: See this answer: [Running Java Programs in Windows 10 Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32365879/5221149)

Comment: 'creating the jar file' is irrelevant; you can run a jar in any version of Java, and you can run non-jar 'exploded' class files in any version of Java

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your use case is; why you think you need to specify a version.  However:

1. Your choice of "java version" is usually determined by *which "java" you choose to run*.

   - If you're using an IDE, you can select one or the other JVM.
   - If you're running from a shell script or a .bat file, you can specify a different path, e.g. `C:\Program Files\java\jdk-11.0.1\bin` or `C:\Program Files\java\jre1.8.0_121\bin`.
2. If you're on Linux, you can use [update-alternatives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315646/update-java-alternatives-vs-update-alternatives-config-java) to specify a different "default" Java version.
3. You can also specify [-version:release](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) on  your Java command line.

Q: Does that answer your question?

Comment: Your #3 `-version:release` no longer exists above 8, and in particular not in 11

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: I'm not sure why the OP is asking about "selecting Java version" in the first place: it strikes me as a bit of a "non-problem" ;) ANYWAY - I just wanted to give as many options as I could think of.  Thank you for pointing out that "-version:release" is now deprecated: I wasn't aware of that.  Partially because I never use it/never needed to use it ;)