# Java: System cannot find the file C:\ ... java.exe

Tags: java, path, javac, java-home

I have installed Java 8 and set my `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` paths and added `%JAVA_HOME%` to the start of the `path` variable.

I created a helloworld.java application and am able to compile it using:

```
javac helloworld.java
```

However, when I try to run:

java helloworld

I get the error:

```
The system cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try this thing. It's the same error.
You should create a links. 
[Try this advice!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864662/how-to-solve-the-error-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-c-programdata-oracle-ja)

Comment: Have you installed just java or the JDK (Java Development Kit) as well?

Comment: I installed just the JDK?

Comment: in system variables section check the `path` variable that is there C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath path in it

Comment: I added it and it hasnt solved it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set %JAVA_HOME%**/bin** to your path variable.

Comment: Obviously you work with Windows. Be sure to exit and restart your console after configuring the path in your system properties. - Do you like to give us your path (set path)?

Comment: Thank you I have solved the issue now. I had set the JDK_HOME and JRE_HOME vars to the wrong path. I have included an answer stating the paths that I used.

Answer (score 5):

1.Just go to C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\

2.You will find there shortcuts for java.exe,javaw.exe,javaws.exe which are pointing to a location where they actually are not existing now

3.Go to the jre location where you have installed java like C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin

4. You will find java.exe,javaw.exe,javaws.exe
5. Create shortcuts for these files and replace with the ones which are present in C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath.

It works

Comment: It was the only solution that worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are blocked from modifying system variables from command line, but are able to open up an *elevated* command prompt, then run a command like this:

`setx \M JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25"`

But of course, change the directory to point to your installed version of java. Note that the JAVA_HOME path does not point into the bin directory, it stops one level above bin.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this issue. To do so I used the advice from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation?lq=1):

Java SE Development Kit 8u25 on a 64-bit Windows 8

Set the following user environment variables (== environment variables of type user variables)

```
•JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
•JDK_HOME  : %JAVA_HOME%
•JRE_HOME  : %JAVA_HOME%\jre
•CLASSPATH : .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib
•PATH      : your-unique-entries;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

(make sure that the longish your-unique-entries does not contain any other references to another Java installation folder.)