# Unable to set a path for JDK

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with setting a path for JDK. Whenever I try to execute a program, I get this message:

> The system cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you really google it before posting it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864662/how-to-solve-the-error-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-c-programdata-oracle-ja

Comment: Maybe these links could help:
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864662/how-to-solve-the-error-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-c-programdata-oracle-ja
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355440/java-system-cannot-find-the-file-c-java-exe

Comment: Yeah I finally got it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Just set %JAVA_HOME%**/bin** to your path variable.

To do this:-

1. Right click My Computer and select Properties.
2. On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables, and then edit JAVA_HOME to point to where the JDK software is located, for example, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02.

Comment: the path that you provided i.e. `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe` doesn't appear to be correct.  It should point to either JRE or JDK folder that you (probably) have in here:

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin

Comment: Ignore the jdk version. It should be your jdk version in the path

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: Just add this bin directory to the PATH variable in Environment Variables(as shown in the answer)

Comment: The same message appears after I compile.

Comment: In the PATH variable I have C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin and %JAVA_HOME%\bin and in JAVA_HOME I have C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin.. What am I missing?

Comment: Oh I got it guys. Thanks so much for all the help

Comment: What was the problem ?

Comment: I deleted C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath from PATH and then exited. Then went back in and added it again. For some reason that worked?