# I am having troubles installing the Movilizer eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, movilizer

While installing the Movilizer eclipse plugin as described [here](https://devtools.movilizer.com/confluence/display/DOC22/Working+with+the+Movilizer+Eclipse+Plug-in) I am constantly getting the following error:

> The Movilizer Eclipse Plug-in is a feature, which was developed to speed up the development process of Movilizer Requests and Movelets when using the Eclipse web service environment.

[image: exception in eclipse]

It seems to be a problem related to SSL certificates not beeing supported by Java.

Comment: Add the error message in your post. The picture is too small and not searchable.

Comment: It all boils down to the problem of getting a self signed SSL certificate into the java truststore. The same issue is covered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617210/how-to-properly-import-a-selfsigned-certificate-into-java-keystore-that-is-avail

Comment: @AndréSchäfer that domain does not use a self-signed certificate. It's signed by the startcom ca, which is in trust stores of all major browsers and operating systems - just not in Oracle Java's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to install the connector we need to import a Movilizer certificate in the keystore of the JDE/JRE that is being used by the eclipse.

1. First of all we should install Eclipse Luna although Mars should work too.
   Now you should be aware of the Java instance that is being used by the eclipse you are trying to enrich with the Movilizer plugin. The following link helps in this regard. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557169/find-out-what-jvm-eclipse-is-running-on). If you find that the path is something like (C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe) which seems to be a new Orcale stunt this link will help you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864662/how-to-solve-the-error-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-c-programdata-oracle-ja) Also make sure that you have the real java bin directory in your system path. You will need this to call the keytool later on.
2. Download the StartCom Root CA certificate and copy it in the Java folder. (e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111)Find the file [here](https://www.startssl.com/certs/crossign/ca-cross-g2.crt)
3. Next we should open up a console but doing it in the admin mode. Find out how you can do int on Windows 10 [here](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-open-elevated-command-prompt-in-windows-10/), Windows 7 [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx).
4. call the following in the console in the same dir as (2) so your jre/jde directory: `keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias mycert -file ca-cross-g2.crt`
5. Sometimes you will have to restart your eclipse.

[image: german command]

Comment: adding a server certificate to a trust store is a bad advice if it's not self signed, which this one is not. instead you should add the root ca's certificate to your trust store...

Answer (score 3):

The domain devtools.movilizer.com seems to use a certificate signed by StartCom. The root certificate of this CA has been included in the trust stores of every major operating system and browser for years. However, Oracle Java comes with its own trust store and it seems Oracle has decided not to inlcude the StartCom CA in it for whatever reasons.

That said, you should download the StartCom Root CA certificate [here](https://www.startssl.com/certs/crossign/ca-cross-g2.crt) and install it with `keytool` like so:

```
cd %JAVA_HOME%\jre
```

```
bin\keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias startcomrootca -file c:\path\to\the\ca-cross-g2.crt`
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue awhile before finding out that the CA certificate that is listed is no longer valid.  The correct ca certificate is ◦Let’s Encrypt Authority X3 (IdenTrust cross-signed) at https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/.  It is listed about mid-way down the page.  How I found this was by looking at the certificate that https://devtools.movilizer.com/eclipseUpdateSite46/ was using in Chrome. I used the following commands

1. cd %JAVA_HOME%
2. bin\keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias statcomrootca -file lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed.cer.
   NOTE: lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed.cer needs to be in your %JAVA_HOME% directory.

Also I was setting up a new computer when I ran into this issue so I did have to set all of my environmental variables as well.