# Issue with Movilizer Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-mars, eclipse-neon, movilizer

I am trying to install movilizer plugin for Eclipse.

Still,after adding StartCom Certificate still i am facing these issue-
[I am having troubles installing the Movilizer eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778897/i-am-having-troubles-installing-the-movilizer-eclipse-plugin)

> Unable to read repository at https://devtools.movilizer.com/eclipseUpdateSite46/content.xml.
>   Unable to read repository at https://devtools.movilizer.com/eclipseUpdateSite46/content.xml.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Any idea how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:

this is exactly the SSL problem following link is addressing:
[I am having troubles installing the Movilizer eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778897/i-am-having-troubles-installing-the-movilizer-eclipse-plugin)

If you correctly import the certificate into your JRE it can require a restart of eclipse to work. 
Another potential problem comes up when you have several JRE versions installed. Please also note that a JDK installation also contains a JRE folder with a certificate store. 
You need to make 100% sure that you add the certificate to the correct store. If you are in doubt which version you need to add it to .... add it to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to your network root certificate to your jre cacerts which eclipse is using.Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40757655/1802348) for very detailed steps. Confirm your eclipse is using very same jre in which you are adding ssl certificate.

take care of following points

1. Double check you edited carets inside jre folder $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts.NOT JDK lib folder!
2. open Preferences > java > installed jre. Grab that path and THATPATH/lib/security/cacerts. This file you have to edit!
3. certificate you are using it is ROOT CA certificate with long validity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" try "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers". I just had the same issue on my Mac.

Then try this:

```
cd $JAVA_HOME/jre
sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias mycert -file /Users/coolik/Downloads/ca-cross-g2.crt
```

Worked for me, hope for you as well.