# Creating a symlink in WAMP server on Windows

Tags: php, include, wamp

I am working on a downloaded version of an application and am getting multiple errors due to:

```
( ! ) Warning: include(/home/USERNAME/public_html/dir/includes/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\dir\includes\db_connection.php on line 6
```

I understand what the error is but I don't want to have to manually change all these includes in the code mainly as doing so means when I update my ive site they will then be wrong.

Is there a way using either WAMP or Windows of creating something like a symlink to tell WAMP that anything in /home/USERNAME/public_html/dir should be served from C:\wamp\www\dir?

I found an option in WAMP for creating an alias but I am not sure if this is the right thing to use?

Comment: No because UNIX and Windows are completly different filesystems. You would have to change your root to c:\whatever\wamp-base

Comment: @bhttoan did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24240393/6597265).

This link https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/278262-mklink-create-use-links-windows.html would serve well too (from the answer above).

Basically you have to use `mklink` Windows command from command prompt (the latter must be run as administrator).

Now. Assume you have WAMP installed and virtual host named `mysite.local` is created and pointinig to the physical `d:\mysite` folder. You want now the files in the folder `f:\otherfolder\realfolder` to be accessible via `mysite.local/otherfolder/somefile.ext` kind of URL.

For this you have to create the symbolic link named `otherfolder` in `d:\mysite` that will point to `f:\otherfolder\realfolder`. You have to execute:

`mklink /D d:\myfolder\otherfolder f:\otherfolder\realfolder`

from Windows command prompt. The link `otherfolder` is created in `d:\myfolder` and you can access files via an URL as mentioned above.